# Codeigniter stop cross domain session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two domains.
1. billing.test.org
2. test.org

test.org is generally use for customer login and billing.test.org is using for application administrator 
Scenario :

test.org have an iframe in which its showing billing.test.org 
so whenever i am logged in via test.org and then going to open billing.test.org in new tab then its showing same logged in person information which is not good for me.
So anyone have idea or something which can help me out to troubleshoot this issue ?

I have already did my homework but can't get perfect solution

My Config file have below information

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "test.org";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Issue :
if user login via test.org then it should not open on billing.test.org until user login manually

All suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: How you are validating session between two .org websites?
Same session variable?

Comment: yup because billing.test.org is main portal and test.org which is using billing.test.org in iframe

Comment: If you are calling test.org in iframe then make a parameter(encrypted) and generate it from billing.test.org. If the valid parameter found then open the iframe. 

test.org/12345
if 12345 found open the frame. if not leave it as a blank or show error message.

Comment: i also did same but how can i get something different in both login that cant get is there any possible way to overwrite cookie_prefix for both login ?

Comment: For example : login via iframe then i had set variable iframe_login,true else that session variable will not set

Comment: you are having a DB which shares both org. If user login in u can encrypt his name as url parameter and share this between them. Just my suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127596/discussion-between-blacmoon-and-ankit-doshi).

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate (session) configuration for your billing.test.org site.
Ideally, different `sess_cookie_name` and `sess_table_name` *and* for your billing site, set the `cookie_domain` to 'billing.test.org'.

On another note, you seem to be using CodeIgniter 2.x, which has been abandoned for over a year now. You should upgrade to version 3 ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for reply but my application built in  HMVC codeigniter with flexigrid and it is very large application now so i cant update it latest version of codeigniter 3.X

Comment: It will require work, surely, but yes you can. That wasn't the main point of my answer though.